# Flat smooth term but significant relashionship GAM

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, partial-plot

I am using GAMs to model the occurrence of a species across 7 sites.
I specified Site as a factor, and the response to each variable (smooths) is allowed to vary across sites.

See a sample of code below:

```r
model <- bam(Y ~ offset(log(offset)) + Site +
    s(X1, by = Site, bs = "tp", m=1, k=15) +
    s(X2, by = Site, bs = "tp", m=1, k=15) +
    s(X3, by = Site, bs = "tp", m=1, k=15) +
    s(X4, by = Site, bs = "tp", m=1, k=15) +
    s(X5, by = Site, bs = "tp", m=1, k=15),
  family = nb, data = data, method = "fREML", cluster = cl,
  discrete = T, rho = r1, AR.start = data$start.event, select=T)
```

The `summary()` function returns significant relationships for most predictors, yet most of the partial dependance plots are completly flat, which puzzles me... On the graph below, each line is a site (as ordered in the model) and each column is a variable (Xi).
Some of these flat smooths come out with low p-values in the GAM summary. Am I missing something there ?

[image]

What could be a reason for this ?

```
Family: Negative Binomial(24.328)
```

Link function: log

```
Formula:
Y ~ offset(log(offset)) + Site + s(X1, by = Site, bs = "tp", 
    m = 1, k = 15) + s(X2, by = Site, bs = "tp", m = 1, 
    k = 15) + s(X3, by = Site, bs = "tp", m = 1, k = 15) + 
    s(X4, by = Site, bs = "tp", m = 1, k = 15) + s(X5, 
    by = Site, bs = "tp", m = 1, k = 15) + s(X6, by = Site, 
    bs = "tp", m = 1, k = 15)

Parametric coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         -5.9005     0.3435 -17.179  < 2e-16 ***
Site2                0.5624     0.6199   0.907   0.3644    
Site3                1.7944     2.9218   0.614   0.5392    
Site4                1.9610     0.3709   5.287  1.4e-07 ***
Site5                0.4001     3.1490   0.127   0.8989    
Site6                2.1811     1.0353   2.107   0.0353 *  
Site7               -1.4402     1.7289  -0.833   0.4049    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                       edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(X1):Site1                      7.566e-01     14 0.067 0.226480    
s(X1):Site2                      1.217e+00     13 0.162 0.104868    
s(X1):Site3                      7.943e-05     12 0.000 0.393940    
s(X1):Site4                      5.057e-01     14 0.042 0.270652    
s(X1):Site5                      1.792e-03     13 0.002  < 2e-16 ***
s(X1):Site6                      1.311e+00     14 0.124 0.202924    
s(X1):Site7                      2.487e-04     13 0.000 0.364268    
s(X2):Site1                      1.763e-05     12 0.000  < 2e-16 ***
s(X2):Site2                      1.077e-04     14 0.000 0.000790 ***
s(X2):Site3                      4.084e-05     13 0.000 0.027148 *  
s(X2):Site4                      1.333e-04     13 0.000 0.000148 ***
s(X2):Site5                      2.063e+00     12 0.285 0.065660 .  
s(X2):Site6                      2.361e-05     14 0.000  < 2e-16 ***
s(X2):Site7                      2.261e+00     13 0.588 0.001283 ** 
s(X3):Site1                      2.525e+00     14 0.391 0.052133 .  
s(X3):Site2                      2.594e-04     14 0.000 0.278446    
s(X3):Site3                      2.544e-05     14 0.000 4.97e-06 ***
s(X3):Site4                      6.631e+00     14 5.045  < 2e-16 ***
s(X3):Site5                      4.185e+00     14 1.352 1.56e-05 ***
s(X3):Site6                      4.474e-05     14 0.000  < 2e-16 ***
s(X3):Site7                      3.923e-01     14 0.041 0.125654    
s(X4):Site1                      2.877e-05     11 0.000 0.078420 .  
s(X4):Site2                      1.118e+00     12 0.175 0.036045 *  
s(X4):Site3                      2.248e-05     10 0.000 3.47e-05 ***
s(X4):Site4                      2.635e-05      9 0.000 0.500774    
s(X4):Site5                      2.885e+00     11 4.209  < 2e-16 ***
s(X4):Site6                      4.288e+00     14 1.094 0.000167 ***
s(X4):Site7                      1.495e+00     13 0.294 0.017538 *  
s(X5):Site1                      4.504e+00     14 3.434  < 2e-16 ***
s(X5):Site2                      2.961e+00     14 1.050 2.48e-05 ***
s(X5):Site3                      3.370e-01     14 0.033 0.228794    
s(X5):Site4                      4.620e+00     14 1.669 3.52e-06 ***
s(X5):Site5                      5.495e-04     14 0.000 0.002088 ** 
s(X5):Site6                      7.250e+00     14 4.226  < 2e-16 ***
s(X5):Site7                      4.742e-01     14 0.034 0.179324    
s(X6):Site1                      8.345e-05     14 0.000  < 2e-16 ***
s(X6):Site2                      1.995e+00     14 0.431 0.008962 ** 
s(X6):Site3                      1.810e+00      9 2.581 2.01e-06 ***
s(X6):Site4                      3.503e-05      8 0.000 0.003170 ** 
s(X6):Site5                      2.583e+00     10 3.750  < 2e-16 ***
s(X6):Site6                      2.980e+00     10 6.812  < 2e-16 ***
s(X6):Site7                      5.722e-05     14 0.000 0.008897 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.771   Deviance explained = 75.3%
fREML = 2326.1  Scale est. = 1         n = 1816
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show the output from `summary()`?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to include the output of the `summary()` function. I also edited the plots to let the scales free. Each row now represent a site; in the same order they appear in the summary. Also added the diagnostic plots for information...

Comment: I suspect it's because you used `m=1` on each of your smooths; this penalizes the first derivative of the smooth, which penalizes deviation from a flat function. You wouldn't see this if you used the default `m=2`. It also a result of the `select=TRUE`, shrinking things back; several of the smooths that are constant functions also have EDFs that are close to 0. Unless you want to fit piecewise linear functions, there's no reason to use `m=1` here. With so many groups, you might also want to use the `fs` basis instead of by smooths.

Comment: Thanks ! That make sense ! I tried again with m=2 and all the smooths ended up flat. But `fs` seems to be working better indeed. Would there be a particular reason for this ? Is it just because of the high number of sites ? When I tried to select which specification to use for each variable, the `fs` models had higher AICs than the by ones so I probably made the wrong choice there. Thank you very much for your help !